# Alternatives to Neuronal Nets and Gradient Boosting for undifferentiable objectives

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models, boosting

It may occur that one has to solve a ML problem but wants to achieve the best result w.r.t a metric that may not be differentiated.
This directly implies that such a metric may not be passed to popular frameworks like `tensorflow` or `xgboost`.
I it may be an alternative to train on a similar metric and then use a less sophisticated machine learning framework on the final layers of a neuronal net.
This would require a machine learning framework that may be optimized for non-differentiable objective values. My question is which frameworks might work here?
e.g. Quadratic Cohen Kappa, like in this challenge: kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection

Comment: What metric are you trying to optimize? What problem are you trying to solve which requires you to use a non-differentiable objective function?

Comment: e.g. Quadratic Cohen Kappa, like in this challenge:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to CV! Could you edit the question to include this information? Comments are intended for clarification of the question, but in the end, the question should be updated so that people who want to answer don't have to read through comment discussions.

Comment: Why is it not sufficient to train with a differentiable function and then measure out of sample performance on the non-differentiable function?

Comment: Might be, but why stop there?

Comment: Because differentiability is the premise of xgboost and neural networks methods, which work so well. At best you’re proposing to make training harder to accomplish a model which has no guarantee of being better.

Comment: The commonly used objective of "accuracy" for object classification is nondifferentiable. Yet, cross-entropy is a pretty decent surrogate.